# Can't get 'edge.create' callback to work with facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use the 'edge.create' callback function of the Facebook javascript SDK to send an alert when a user clicks the like button on a page. Ultimately my goal is to have it regenerate styles on the page so that it can resize the facebook widget div dynamically when clicked. I cannot get the callback to work even for the alert though.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script   src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=216985861663967&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
    <script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {
            alert('Liked');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? When the button is clicked it gives the error:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

and later says Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I'm guessing you're testing in Chrome/Safari on a local server?

### Chrome/Safari

Try setting your Like Button URL to an existing Web address:

```
<fb:like href="http://google.com" ...
```

An important note is that the alert depends on the Like's success, which depends on the URL being reachable by Facebook. You won't be able to Like a URL that only exists on your local server (ex. http://localhost:3000/my-page.html). Obviously Liking Google is a test fix; you can instead push your code to a staging server for the same effect, but it takes more time and effort.

When I make this change the Like Button and alert work in Chrome 12 for Mac, but I still see the same error as you. I think Chrome is just sensitive with iframes; I doubt the error can be avoided.

### Firefox

If I make the above change, it still doesn't work in Firefox 5 for Mac. I get the error `e.root is undefined` from Facebook's all.js and the Like Button doesn't even appear.

If I move the `all.js` and `FB.Event.subscribe()` scripts below the `fb-root` div, the Like Button shows up and the alert works with no errors.

### Internet Explorer

According to [Facebook's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you need to add Facebook's XML namespace to your `<html>` tag for the button to render in Internet Explorer:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate your application id.
If you still not have any app, just create it in developer section of facebook.

Example:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB._https = true;
        FB.init({appId: 'YOURAPP', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, channelURL : 'http://www.YOURSITE/channel.html'});
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            alert('Liked');
        });
    };
</script>
```

P.S. Inside http://www.YOURSITE/channel.html file, put next row -

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `alert()` in a Facebook application, at least not in Chrome (if Firefox still allows it, they probably won't for much longer).

Use `console.log()` instead, and open the Javascript console to see the messages that are emitted.